# how can i insert no more than 5 sentences and no more than 50 letters per each sentence in C

Tags: c, arrays, max, letter

before each sentence it needs to say the number of the sentence im writing. starting the count from one.
what i mean is:

```
How many sentences you want to enter [1-5]? 
2
sentence 1: write what you want
sentence 2: here as long as its less then 50 letters
```

my problem is that i dont know how to limit the number of letters, without needing to insert them all.
if i write

```
 for(i=0; i<50; i++)
```

i will need to enter all the 50 letters, but if i want i need to be able to write even only 1.
so that is what i have done so far: (note that i dont need to ask the user how many letters he wants to enter)

```
char text[5][50]={0};
int x=0, i=0, n=0, m=0;

   printf("How many sentences you want to enter [1-5]?\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("how many letters [1-50]?\n");
   scanf("%d", &m);

   for (x=1; x<=n; x++)// will print max of 5 sentences
   {
       printf("Sentence %d: \n", x);
        for(i=0; i<m; i++)// will print max of 50 letters
        {
            scanf(" %c", &text[x][i]);
        }
   }
```

thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What would you like the computer to do, if someone tries to type the 51st letter?

Comment: nothing. i asume he wont enter more then 50

Comment: in that case, could `%s` do what you want?

Comment: Also note that, in the typical case, you'll need to size your array for 51 characters to read 50 letters (to include the string terminator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  if(fgets(text,50,stdin) != NULL) /* Read just 50 character */
  {
     // Do your stuff
   }
}
```

PS: `fgets()` comes with a newline character

Answer (score 0):

There is still an error.

```
for (x=1; x<=n; x++)
```

will cause an indexing error when `x==5`. *Always* maintain your indexing to suit the language. Use

```
for (x=0; x<n; x++)
```

Add 1 for human information

```
printf("Sentence %d: \n", x + 1);
```

And as @cmatsuoka wrote, the array should be

```
char text[5][51]={0};
```